# The "Right" flow in creating a Rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, workflow, project

I'm starting out with Ruby on Rails and I know of a few stuff already, but I was wondering if there was a "right" way of going about developing a project. Right now, I would create my models first using [script/generate model MyModel] then modifying them until I feel they are complete enough. Then I'd go for [script/generate scaffold MyModel] so I don't need to do as much coding for the views. Lastly I modify the views and add more models then scaffold some more for other features I might need.

Would there be a better way of doing this? Especially in the context of working with a team in developing a project? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure everyone has their own workflow, but I think a typical one is this:

1. Specify the "domain" your project. This probably sounds silly, but before you get started you should really think about what exactly your website is going to offer. It doesn't need to be specific down to the last detail, but should have an idea so that you can perform the next step...
2. Design your database schema. I usually just plan this out on paper. There's a real art to creating a normalized database. Think of everything that needs to be "permanent" in your app, because it will have to be in the database and accounted for, with as little duplication as possible.

After this I usually do as you say: create my models (and migration scripts along the way). The main thing you want to get down in your models first is the associations with other models.

The next part depends on how comfortable you are as a developer in Rails. A lot of people enjoy the test driven development approach (TDD), and will write Unit tests (Rails provides excellent facilities for writing these, and rake tasks to run them). However, since you're just learning, you may want to write your tests after you implement your model business logic.

The road after this is pretty much up to you. You can work on your views/controllers/models as you need to. That's one of the beauties of Rails and agile development, you don't need a lot of boiler plate code to get started.

I'm probably weird in this, but I usually design my front page and get some basic CSS going, as I find I am more productive if my results are semi-nice looking.

I would probably avoid generating scaffolds though...I think you'll learn a lot more about the framework and spend less time removing unwanted code if you generate the individual pieces themselves.

In the context of developing with a team, things will probably be different. If you have a lot of complex business logic, some people may spend most of their time writing model code, while people more on the design side will be implementing view code. But you will have to meet in the middle of course, which will get easier as your project grows and becomes more modular.  Just remember to use a version control system! Subversion if you want something easy to use and learn, Git if you're up for a challenge.